# NodeJs: Socket.io use() method

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I can't find any document that make an understanding about use() method. Please explane socket.use() method.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace

Comment: I saw that docs but I still don't understand use().

Comment: What _specifically_ don't you understand? The documentation seems pretty clear, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

`socket.use()` is basically where you can add middleware functions, which just means that the function passed as the parameter for the`socket.use()` function is executed for every piece of info received.

Here's the socket.io docs

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn

Answer (score 0):

`socketio.use()` method is same like as `express_app.use()` method , means both are used for passing middleware-functions , where middleware-functions can control/manipulate every upcoming requests/response on the server.